# Remapping an Array in Java 8 Using Math and Streams

Tags: java, arrays, math, java-8, java-stream

Apache commons math has a RealVector interface support a mapToSelf fluid interface that works like this:

```
 RealVector result = v.mapAddToSelf(3.4).mapToSelf(new Tan()).mapToSelf(new Power(2.3));
```

If I had a `double[]` array how would I do something similar with Java 8 streams and Java Math?  The same array has to be reused.

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you already have an array and you want to modify it in place, you can use [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-double:A-java.util.function.IntToDoubleFunction-):

```
Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> Math.pow(Math.tan(arr[i] + 3.4), 2.3));
```

And just in case you *don't* want to modify the original array, you can create a `DoubleStream` from it and map each element:

```
double[] res = 
    DoubleStream.of(arr).map(d -> Math.pow(Math.tan(d + 3.4), 2.3)).toArray();
```

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks - Appreciate the note on the DoubleStream as well!